# How to view pdf from url (view option in android app)?

Tags: android, pdf

I am making an android app in which user can download PDF and also can view it, I want to ask that how to make view option.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Google Drive viewer.

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: You mean I put this code in listener and what is first two url for?

Comment: First Url Is Url of your pdf

Comment: The second Link Is connect to google drive and show the pdf in webView

Comment: TAG-Tag has private access in 'android.support.v4.add.fragment activity and webView- webView cannot resolve symbol webview

Comment: Create For Activity Ex:Named = WebView
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted

Comment: View This Steps For Build Your WebView In Your App

Comment: WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://famousknowledgeblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/e0a485e0a495e0a4ace0a4b0-e0a4ace0a580e0a4b0e0a4ace0a4b2-e0a495e0a580-e0a4aae0a4b9e0a4b2e0a580-e0a4aee0a581e0a4b2e0a4bee0a495e0a4be.pdf");
I write this code from your given link. When I click on button the app closes

Comment: @PrashantJha The Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url)

not must for you

Answer (score 0):

To load the PDF on PDF Supporting apps in your device

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(msg.getData()), Constants.MIME_PDF);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, getString(R.string.chooser_title));
chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // optional

startActivity(chooser);
```

Its always better to check for exception to avoid some other issue .`isActivityForIntentAvailable` is used for checking your device doesn't have any pdf supporting intents

```
public static boolean isActivityForIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: is I have to make a new activity for pdf view